# Get text value only from NSXMLElement without the text of child nodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsxml, nsxmlelement

I use `KissXML`, it is a drop replacement for `NSXMLDocument`, etc. 
This is contents of my `NSXMLElement`:

```
<ar>
    <k>baker</k>
    <tr>ˈbeɪkə</tr>
    baker пекарь, булочник
</ar>
```

I want to get the text value of a `NSXMLElement Node` without the text of all child nodes. So, it should return only:

```
baker пекарь, булочник
```

This is not working:

```
_articleText = [xmlElement stringValue];
```

It returns everything, including text of tr and k child nodes.

P.S. 
I got this ar node using `XPath` and I'm searching for `XPath` solution preferably, I do not want to remove substrings.

```
NSArray *array = [self.xmlDocument nodesForXPath:@"/xdxf/ar" error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'array' contains only one element, then 's' will contain the string of interest:

```
NSArray *array = [self.xmlDocument nodesForXPath:@"/xdxf/ar" error:&error];
if([array count] > 0) { 
    NSArray *childrenOfAr = [array[0] children];    
    for(NSXMLNode *n in childrenOfAr) {
        if([n kind] == NSXMLTextKind) {
             NSString *s = [n stringValue];
        }
    }
}
```

A faster way is to look for text() in the Xpath query:

```
NSArray *array = [self.xmlDocument nodesForXPath:@"/xdxf/ar/text()" error:&error];
if([array count] > 0) { 
    NSString *s = [array[0] stringValue]; 
}
```